# Mesh explodes when saving or undoing sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I have been working on a human mesh and wanted to make a pose for a render and needed to do some slight sculpting after the pose. For some reason when trying to sculpt and then undoing or saving something the model just ... explodes ... thats the best I can explain it.

[image]

I am using Shapekeys for some facial features and have an active multires for sculpting.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: are you set at frame 0/1 of your timeline and all the pose things are dissabled? This pretty much happens if you have some animation on your object and try to sculpt without applied/baked animation

Comment: timeline is on frame 0 yes, again though its not intented to be an animation just a pose/image. The armature though is still active, is that the issue then? Combination of posed armature, keyshapes and sculpting?

Comment: I dont know if "bumping" is a thing, but I still have the issue. Even when setting all Shapekeys to 0 does it still happen.

The only "fix" i have found so far would be to remove all shapekeys, but thats not gonna work for animations and stuff.

This pose also has no animations. At least not intented ones. I checked the animations tab and couldnt find anything in terms of keyframes